# How do I use an index of strings in an array to display alongside text using UIImage in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, uiimage

So I have an array of flowers.

```
var flowers = ["Waterlily", "Sunflower", "Rose", "Magnolia", "Lily", "Jonquil", "Echinacea"]
```

I am trying to convert these strings in the array to lowercase, and append .jpg at the end of them so I can display the pictures in my resources folder.

Here is my code for that:

```
    Image(UIImage(named: flowers[index].lowercased() + ".jpg"))
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 60)
```

**My error is that I cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type 'String'.**

Here's my full code:

```
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View
{
    var flower: String = ""
    
    var flowers = ["Waterlily", "Sunflower", "Rose", "Magnolia", "Lily", "Jonquil", "Echinacea"]
    
    var body: some View
    {
        
        List(0..<flowers.count)
        {
            index in
            
            
            HStack
                {
                    
                    
                    Image(UIImage(named: flowers[index].lowercased() + ".jpg"))
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 60)
                    
                    
                    Text(self.flowers[index])
                }
        }
    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong initialiser for the `Image` View.

use `Image(uiImage: UIImage)` instead in that case. (Note that the parameter name / argument label is required.)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/init(uiimage:)

(changed your code to work)

```swift
struct ContentView: View
{
    var flower: String = ""
    
    var flowers = ["Waterlily", "Sunflower", "Rose", "Magnolia", "Lily", "Jonquil", "Echinacea"]
    
    var body: some View
    {
        List(0..<flowers.count) { index in
            HStack {
                // uiImage argument label is required
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: flowers[index].lowercased() + ".jpg"))
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 60)
                    
                    
                Text(self.flowers[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a list of all initialisers for the `Image` View
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image

Swift documentation for function parameters and argument labels
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166

Comment: thanks! I had to use self.flowers[index] for this to work.

Comment: ahh, yes. makes sense. (not required anymore with swift 5.3)